# The interval [0,1] andd [3,5] are equivalent. Is my proof correct?

Tags: proof-verification

> The intervals $[0,1]$ and $[3,5]$ are equivalent.

My proof goes like this.

> Proof. To show that the two sets are equivalent, we should show a bijection between them. Consider the function $f:[0,1] \to [3,5]$ such that $f(x)=2x+3$.
>
> Since $f$ is  linear, it is bijective.
> Therefore, the intervals $[0,1]$ and $[3,5]$ are equivalent.

I am not sure if this is right. Assuming that this is correct, is it better to show that $f$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive?

If this is wrong, what is the right way of proving?

Sorry if this is so simple.

Comment: In set theory, two sets are equivalent if and only if they have the same elements. Therefore, $[3,5]$ and $[0,1]$ are *not* equal. The correct term to use is *isomorphic*; bijections are isomorphisms in the category of sets.

As far as your proof goes, your function is fine, but it's not justified correctly. Why is it bijective? Try appealing to the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: As far as I know, set A is equivalent to set B if there exists a bijection between A  and  B. I'm not talking about equal sets.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: You are confusing "equal" and "equivalent"; the OP's use of terms is correct. For instance, $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Z$ are not equal, but are equivalent.

Comment: You may use the words "equipotent" or "equinumerous" for the relationship you deal with, equivalent is very non-standard. Your function is fine, and if you have a result stating that an affine (probably what you call linear, but that function isn't actual linear) function is a bijection between it's domain and range, I would be happy if you just added a argument about using (and why you can use) it. And it is neither reflexive nor transitive (I don't even think those terms can be defined  meaningfully when the domain and co-domain are different as here) so that is just meaningless.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The function is not symmetric since there is the point (0,3) but not the point (3,0)  because f is not even defined in 3.
Your argument is correct, if you're talking about equivalence as topological spaces (showing there's a continuous bijection between both spaces). May be you could argument that it is bijective because it has a left and right inverse: g(x)=(x-3)/2 and continuity is clear because it is a composition of continuous functions.